# Tortoise SVN - AnkhSvn (VisualStudio)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Is there any solution to see live commit changes done by other team-mate(s) developers working on the same project? Any solution to see asychronous msg for commit changes are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up-to-date TortoiseSVN builds include [Project Monitor](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-projectmonitor.html) tool that will notify you about the commits your colleagues make. The tool provides similar set of features that standalone [Commit Monitor](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html) tool has.

Answer (score 3):

In TortoiseSVN, you can use the Check for Modifications dialog and click Check Repository to show all changes in the repository which you have not retrieved by running Update.

In AnkSVN, go to the [Pending Changes window and click Refresh](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=326363).